# Rubygems point to unknown directory on macOS

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I don't remember what I have done but FastLane is trying to find a `Gemfile` in a **deleted directory**.

So I cannot use FastLane anymore because the `Gemfile` is always not found.

```sh
iMac:~ machine$ fastlane --help
/Users/machine/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/project-machine/ios/Gemfile not found
```

The issue also occurs when I try to run a command with `gem` like:

- ```sh
   gem -v
  ```
- ```sh
    gem --help
  ```

```sh
iMac:~ machine$ gem --help
/Users/machine/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/project-machine/ios/Gemfile not found
```

**How I can revert my gem installation or something else without reinstalling the operating system?**

**Ruby version:** `ruby 2.3.7p456 2018-03-28 revision 63024 universal x86_64-darwin18`
**macOS:** `10.14.4`

Comment: If you get the error message for all gems (including `gem` itself) this is probably not a fastlane issue, but something related to bundler, gems in general or even ruby.

Comment: @janpio yes sorry it's a gem issue not a fastlane issue i will edit the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day and a night of hard work, it seems that the issue was solved by doing in a macOS terminal:

```sh
unset BUNDLE_GEMFILE
```